# how to insert an object in database

Tags: kohana-3

How can I insert an object in database in kohana 3?

My code is:

```
$application = DB::query(Database::SELECT,"SELECT * FROM application_settings WHERE 'id'  = 1")->as_object()->execute();
$application -> google_analytical = $_POST['google_txt'];
$application = DB::insert('application_settings',$application)->execute();
$this->template->inner->status_msg = "Record has been saved successfully";
```

I want to insert the object named application into the database.

Answer (score 0):

`DB::insert()` [syntax](http://kohanaframework.org/3.0/guide/database/query/builder#insert) is:

```
DB::insert('application_settings', $application_columns)
   ->values($application_values)
   ->execute();
```

By the way, why do you want to INSERT new record instead of [UPDATE](http://kohanaframework.org/3.0/guide/database/query/builder#update)ing an existing one?

```
DB::update('application_settings')
   ->set(array('google_analytical' => $_POST['google_txt']))
   ->where('id', '=', $application->id))
   ->execute();
```

**UPD**. You are looking for a single row, so:

```
// insert it after DB::query() call
$application = current($application);
```

Comment: yes i should use update... but this is giving error          ErrorException [ Notice ]: Undefined property: Database_MySQL_Result::$id .... please reply